# OneDrive to PowerBI connection

Tags: powerbi, onedrive

I'm facing an issue in connecting to OneDrive with Power BI. Please assist to make the connection successful.  Here I'm attaching the screenshot of the error below. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to authenticate it using anonymous credentials which is not supported, you'll need to use your organizational account to log into it. It is best outlined in this document from Microsoft on how to access files in OneDrive

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-use-onedrive-business-links